# job offer pulled away from hiring managers after they found out about DWAI from 4 years ago I was honest with HR but managers didn't know prior to HR

Tags: human-resources, sales

Job offer has been rescinded after the hiring mangers found out about a DWAI ("Driving While Ability Impaired") from 4 years ago which has come to light following going through DMV (Department of Motor Vehicles) background check and on-boarding requirements with HR.

Manager says that they have to back of the offer because I was not completely transparent and upfront with him about it first during our interview and previous meetings. Hiring personnel also said they have to back any from entire offer.

I was still going to try to set up a meeting with the President to talk and possibly explain but I honestly didn't even bring it up as it was an oversight and after thought. I am trying to still save the job opportunity and hopefully the president will reconsider me.

Driving every day is a must as it is a sales job. I even just was let go from a position where I had a company issued vehicle along with company insurance. For this new company if I'm still considered I was going to have to drive my own vehicle and supply my own insurance so I didn't even thing to bring it up.

What words can I say or what actions can I say or do to save this job opportunity? I know I have asked God to forgive me and he has shown me forgiveness for my mistakes. How do you get a potential employer to forgive or to reconsider?

The crazy part is I have been honest, open, and transparent with every other employer, unfortunately I did't mention it to this company. I by no means didn't  mean to omit it or neglect bringing it up. I have nothing to hide I just unfortunately forgot to bring it up sooner.

What do I do and say to save this opportunity? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? And is a driving offence relevant to the job?

Comment: Hi Adam, this question is really hard to read, which will probably turn people off from answering it. Can you add some paragraphs, so it's not a wall of text please?

Comment: Are you in the US?  Which state did the DWAI occur in (as it may be a traffic infraction rather than a felony or misdemeanour) https://www.avvo.com/legal-answers/i-have-a-dwai-on-my-record-and-i-need-to-know-how--3565705.html

Comment: What's a DWAI, what's a DMV? Please add context, this is the internet, not everybody is living in the US. While you are at it, please add a few linebreaks, too.

Answer (score 1):

> What do I do and say to save this opportunity?

You tried praying, you tried explaining. Multiple people have said no despite you utilising your sales charm skills. You're out of options.

Answer (score 1):

> What words can I say or what actions can I say or do to save this job opportunity?

At this point probably nothing. Firstly because:

> Driving every day is a must as it is a sales job.

So if you re-offend/get caught again then in many places this is going to mean a suspended license for a decent chunk of time at the very least which means regardless of whose vehicle and insurance you would be using it's a risk factor for employing you in role where you need to drive.

> The crazy part is I have been honest, open, and transparent with every other employer unfortunately I did't mention it to this company. I by know means didnt not mean to omit it or neglect bringing it up. I have nothing to hide I just unfortunately forgot to bring it up sooner.

This hits the nail on the head as to the second, possibly even more significant factor. You may have genuinely forgotten to bring this up but the end result is the same you lied (by way of omission) about something that would be a pertinent fact. You can't un-ring that bell. You can try being honest, you say

> I know I have asked God to forgive me and he has shown me forgiveness for my mistakes.

Which I'm sure is of great comfort to you personally it doesn't really offer much to anyone else trying to assess the risk of recidivism. As far as I know most Gods don't offer personal character references in the majority of cases.

So this is on you to try and address. To do that you need to address *both* the failure to tell them about this and also the issue of potential future scenarios. Tell the president that you made a mistake in not bringing it up. Be prepared to explain what changes you've made in your life to prevent this occurring again, something like:

> I realize that I should have been upfront with this information in earlier conversations. When I messed up four years ago I realized that this had the potential to severely ruin my career so since then I've made sure to be extra careful about never driving while impaired and if I know I need to drive I'm conscious never to have too much. It was the wake up call I needed and I'm not the person I was four years ago.

It might help, it might not. But at this point you haven't really got anything to lose by trying it. As things stand you are losing the opportunity so a slim chance is better than none.